# Как вызвать функцию из message handler в callback handler?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
async def menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.username in listOfAdmins:
        buttons = [
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Изменить значение текста", callback_data = 'change'),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отправить текст", callback_data = 'send')
        ]
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        file = openTextToRead()
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,f'Привет, @{message.from_user.username}!\nТекущее сообщение: <b>{file.read()}</b>\n Меню:', parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboard)
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="change")
async def changingText(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.from_user.username in listOfAdmins:
        await call.message.answer('Отправь текст который будет рассылаться(старый сотрётся если был).')
        await WritingText.enter_text.set()
        await call.answer()
@dp.message_handler(state=WritingText.enter_text)
async def writeText(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    file = openTextToWrite()
    await state.update_data(text=message.text)
    text = await state.get_data()
    file.write(text['text'])
    await state.finish()
    file.close()
    await message.answer('Успешно!')
    await menu(message)
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="send")
async def sendingText(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.from_user.username in listOfAdmins:
        file = openTextToRead()
        await bot.send_message(GROUP_ID, file.read())
        await call.message.answer('Успешно!')
        await call.answer()
        file.close()
        await menu(call.message) # Нужно вызвать здесь. в этом коде ничего не выводит, но и ошибок нет
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Какую функцию вы хотите вызвать, из приведенного кода ничего не понятно

Comment: я оставил комментарий там, где я хочу вызвать и что.

Comment: @mazik7512 А где изменения в вашей правке? Все то же самое, только пробелы между функциями.

Comment: Ваш код был абсолютно нечитаем

Comment: Объясните конкретно, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Мне требуется вызвать функцию menu после выполнения callback.